# Adding Search Display Controller in UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I want to implement a `UISearchDisplayController` in a `UIViewController`, hence there is no `UITableView`  implemented. I created the `UISearchBar` and `UISearchDisplayController` and implemented the corresponding delegate methods.

When I run the app and try searching, the table view that should be shown with the search results do not appear. To explain more my app UI, the `UIViewController` has a map and the search bar is placed in the navigation controller.

What I understood for now, it seems like I should implement a table view in order to be reused for the search results. However, there is no place/need to place a table view. What can I do to fix this? Any hints?

Here is the code how I implemented everything:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

_search = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 30)];
[_search setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
[_search setPlaceholder:@"Search"];
self.navigationItem.titleView = _search;

_searchArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Hi", nil];

_searchDisplay = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:_search contentsController:self];
_searchDisplay.delegate = self;
_searchDisplay.searchResultsDataSource = self;
_searchDisplay.searchResultsDelegate = self;
[_searchDisplay setActive:YES animated:YES];

filteredResults = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];}



 -(void) filterForSearchText:(NSString *) text scope:(NSString *) scope
{
    [filteredResults removeAllObjects]; // clearing filter array
    NSPredicate *filterPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[c] %@",text]; // Creating filter condition
    filteredResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[_searchArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filterPredicate]]; // filtering result
    NSLog(@"search %@", filteredResults);
}

    #pragma mark - UISearchDisplayDelegate Methods
-(BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self filterForSearchText:searchString scope:[[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[[[self searchDisplayController] searchBar] selectedScopeButtonIndex] ]];

    return YES;
}

-(BOOL) searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
    [self filterForSearchText:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text scope:
     [[self.searchDisplayController.searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You have implemented the table view methods? You should have as this controller is the `searchResultsDataSource`.

Comment: @Wain oh yes i did implement them but didn't include them above. I'm sure the identifier and the array user for number of rows are right. By the way, my searchResultsDataSource is set as 'self'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: So which methods are called? Searching? Search delegate will display? Table data source? What are the filtered search results logged?

Comment: the filteredResults are the search results. For the sake of testing i only added one object. Besides, i created a table view and added it to the view and i set [self.table reloadData]; in filterForSearchText:scope: and the search is working fine. so i guess the problem is that i should add at least one table view so that it works or else it won't.

Comment: You don't need another table, the search controller provides one. But you need to look at which methods are called and aren't.

Comment: okay i managed to let the table view appear, you're right it provides a table view by default. since the search bar is in the navigation bar i added this: [_searchDisplay setDisplaysSearchBarInNavigationBar:YES]; however, the bar isn't placed in the title only (as it should be) it's taking the entire naviBar. do you know any antidote for that?

Comment: what is wrong with using the title view?

Answer (score -1):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RoleDetailTVC.h" // so this class can be an RoleDetailTVCDelegate
#import "CoreDataTableViewController.h" // so we can fetch
#import "Role.h"

@interface RolesTVC : CoreDataTableViewController <RoleDetailTVCDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSFetchedResultsController *fetchedResultsController;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Role *selectedRole;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *searchResults;

@end



#import "RolesTVC.h"
#import "Role.h"
#import "ModelCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface RolesTVC ()
{
    NSMutableArray *objects;

}

@end

@implementation RolesTVC
@synthesize fetchedResultsController = __fetchedResultsController;
@synthesize managedObjectContext = __managedObjectContext;
@synthesize selectedRole;
@synthesize searchResults;


-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    if(self){
        for (int i=1; i<100; i++) {
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is the fabulous Row %d",i];
            [objects addObject:str];
        }
    }
    return self;
}



//This function is where all the magic happens
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    //1. Setup the CATransform3D structure
    CATransform3D rotation;
    rotation = CATransform3DMakeRotation( (90.0*M_PI)/180, 0.0, 0.7, 0.4);
    rotation.m34 = 1.0/ -600;


    //2. Define the initial state (Before the animation)
    cell.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor]CGColor];
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(10, 10);
    cell.alpha = 0;

    cell.layer.transform = rotation;
    cell.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0.5);

    //!!!FIX for issue #1 Cell position wrong------------
    if(cell.layer.position.x != 0){
        cell.layer.position = CGPointMake(0, cell.layer.position.y);
    }

    //4. Define the final state (After the animation) and commit the animation
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"rotation" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.8];
    cell.layer.transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    cell.alpha = 1;
    cell.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}


//Helper function to get a random float
- (float)randomFloatBetween:(float)smallNumber and:(float)bigNumber {
    float diff = bigNumber - smallNumber;
    return (((float) (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1)) / RAND_MAX) * diff) + smallNumber;
}

- (UIColor*)colorFromIndex:(int)index{
    UIColor *color;

    //Purple
    if(index % 3 == 0){
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.93 green:0.01 blue:0.55 alpha:1.0];
        //Blue
    }else if(index % 3 == 1){
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:0.68 blue:0.94 alpha:1.0];
        //Blk
    }else if(index % 3 == 2){
        color = [UIColor blackColor];
    }
    else if(index % 3 == 3){
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.00 green:1.0 blue:0.00 alpha:1.0];
    }


    return color;

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Fetched Results Controller section
- (void)setupFetchedResultsController
{
    // 1 - Decide what Entity you want
    NSString *entityName = @"Role"; // Put your entity name here
    //NSLog(@"Setting up a Fetched Results Controller for the Entity named %@", entityName);

    // 2 - Request that Entity
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:entityName];
    [request setFetchLimit:100];
    // 3 - Filter it if you want
    //request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Role.name = Blah"];

    // 4 - Sort it if you want
    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name"
                                                                                     ascending:YES
                                                                                      selector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
    // 5 - Fetch it
    self.fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                        managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                          sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                                                                                   cacheName:nil];
    [self performFetch];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self setupFetchedResultsController];
}

/**
 *  iCloud
 *
 *  @param  note    Check PersonTVC
 */
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)note {
    //NSLog(@"Underlying data changed ... refreshing!");
    [self performFetch];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [ADVThemeManager customizeTableView:self.tableView];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    /*
     * Refresh this view whenever data changes iCloud
     */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadFetchedResults:)
                                                 name:@"RolesTVCSomethingChanged"
                                               object:[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]];


}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    /**
     *  iCloud
     *
     */
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];

    /**
     *  Search Function
    */
    self.searchResults = nil;
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RolesCell";

    ModelCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ModelCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }



    // Configure the cell...
    Role *role = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLbl.text = role.name;
    cell.zoneLbl.text = role.zones;
    cell.checkoutLbl.text = role.checkout;

    //Set the accessory type.
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


    //Configure the cell font
    cell.zoneLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"eurostile-oblique" size:18.0];
    cell.nameLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"eurostile-oblique" size:18.0];
    cell.checkoutLbl.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"eurostile-oblique" size:18.0];

    return cell;
}



#pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return [self.searchResults count];
    }
    else
    {
        return [[[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section] numberOfObjects];
    }

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 75.f;
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view Methods
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

        [self.tableView beginUpdates]; // Avoid  NSInternalInconsistencyException

        // Delete the role object that was swiped
        Role *roleToDelete = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        //NSLog(@"Deleting (%@)", roleToDelete.name);
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:roleToDelete];
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];

        // Delete the (now empty) row on the table
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        [self performFetch];

        [self.tableView endUpdates];


        NSError *error = nil;
        if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
            NSLog(@"Error! %@",error);
            abort();
        }

    }
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Add Role Segue"])
    {
        // NSLog(@"Setting RolesTVC as a delegate of RoleDetailTVC");
        RoleDetailTVC *roleDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        roleDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // NSLog(@"Creating a new role and passing it to RoleDetailTVC");
        Role *newRole = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Role"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

        roleDetailTVC.role = newRole;
        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        roleDetailTVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    else if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Role Detail Segue"])
    {
        // NSLog(@"Setting RolesTVC as a delegate of RoleDetailTVC");
        RoleDetailTVC *roleDetailTVC = segue.destinationViewController;
        roleDetailTVC.delegate = self;

        // Store selected Role in selectedRole property
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        self.selectedRole = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        // NSLog(@"Passing selected role (%@) to RoleDetailTVC", self.selectedRole.name);
        roleDetailTVC.role = self.selectedRole;
        // Hide bottom tab bar in the detail view
        roleDetailTVC.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
    }
    else {
       // NSLog(@"Unidentified Segue Attempted!");
    }
}

- (void)theSaveButtonOnTheRoleDetailTVCWasTapped:(RoleDetailTVC *)controller
{
    // do something here like refreshing the table or whatever

    // close the delegated view
    [controller.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
}

// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
    return YES;
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    UIAlertView *alertDialog;
    alertDialog = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                   initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Memory Problem", @"Hafıza Problemi")
                   message: NSLocalizedString(@"Please Close Some Applications!", @"Hafıza Problemi")
                   delegate: nil
                   cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok"
                   otherButtonTitles: nil];
    [alertDialog show];
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

@end
```